Custom Approval Process with Parallel Approval
I'm really having a hard time to meet this objective because the Standard Salesforce Approval Process does not provide the Parallel Approval
Here's what we have done so far

Salesforce Flow is the main development method
Can use Apex Trigger but very minimal because the client wants to have some in-house developers to continue maintaining it.

I have this Custom Object called SalesApproval__c, Consenters__c, Approvers__c, SalesApproval_MasterData_Consenters__c and SalesApproval_MasterData_Approvers__c
The basic concept is, the SalesApproval__c needs 3 Consenters and 1 Approver for it to be finally considered at Approved. The problem is, these Consenters and Approver should belong to a Group (Standard Object of Salesforce)
So for example:
The moment the SalesApproval__c record has been created, the Salesforce Flow (Screen Flow + Record-Triggered Flow) will auto assign Groups to that SalesApproval__c. How do I auto-assign? It's through the SalesApproval_MasterData_Consenters__c and SalesApproval_MasterData_Approvers__c mentioned above.
They're already prepared even before I have created a record for the SalesApproval__c. The problem is we cannot directly create a relationship to the Group Standard Object of Salesforce...
My questions are:

Is there a way for me to create a picklist or direct relationship to the Group Standard Object? I have already prepared a Screen Flow and Record-Triggered flow that automatically assigns Consenters and Approver to my SalesApproval but, I cannot determine which of them should be the only ones to see the Approve and Reject button coz I'm having a hard time to link them to the Group
Or maybe, do you guys have an idea how can I create the Parallel Approval in the Standard Salesforce Approval Process please?

Thank you in advance for your kind guidance!

what logic drives you to go to decide Group. Maintain a custom meta data to drive logic of salesapproval DATA to group Data.  you can do parallel approvals with static group name or configurable number of users, but u cant implement dynamically picking group with standard parallel approval process.
